# How to initialize state with api's data

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, axios

I'm creating a React/Redux app that fetches data from an api (pokeapi.co). I fetch data using `axios`. When I display data on react components, it results in an error that data is `undefined`. After some digging, I find that my state at first returns initial state which is empty object then it returns the api data. but it dont display on react. I'm new to React so I'm guessing it has to do with the axios asynchronous functionality. How do you set state with api's initial data or wait on rendering the data till state has api's data?

Here is the Reducer

```
function pokemonReducer(state={}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case pokemonsActions.GET_POKEMON_SUCCESS:
            {
                return  {...state, data: action.payload.data}
            }

        default:
            {
                return state;
            }
    }
}

export default pokemonReducer
```

Here is the action

```
export const GET_POKEMON_SUCCESS = 'GET_POKEMON_SUCCESS'
export const GET_POKEMON_ERROR = 'GET_POKEMON_ERROR'

function getPokemonSuccess(response) {
    return {
        type: GET_POKEMON_SUCCESS,
        payload: response
    }

}

function getPokemonError(err) {
    return {
        type: GET_POKEMON_ERROR,
        payload: err
    }
}
export function getPokemon() {
    return (disp,getState) => 
             {
                return pokeAPI.getPokeAPI()
                              .then((response) => { disp(getPokemonSuccess(response))})
                              .catch((err)=> disp(getPokemonError(err)))

             }
}
```

Store

```
const loggerMiddleware = createLogger()
const middleWare= applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware,loggerMiddleware);

const store = createStore(rootReducer,preloadedState,
 compose(middleWare, typeof window === 'object' && typeof window.devToolsExtension !== 'undefined'
  ? window.devToolsExtension() : (f) => f
))


const preloadedState=store.dispatch(pokemonActions.getPokemon())

export default store
```

in React component

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    pokemons:state.pokemons
  }
}

    class PokemonAbility extends React.Component {

        render(){
            return (
                <div>
                <div className="header">
                  <h1>Fetch Poke Api with axios</h1>
                 </div>
                    <main>
                    <h3> Display pokemons abilities </h3>
                        <p>{this.props.pokemons.data.count}</p>
                    </main>
                </div>
                )
        }
    }


    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps
    )(PokemonAbility)
```

Api data example

```
{
    "count": 292,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/1/",
            "name": "stench"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/2/",
            "name": "drizzle"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/3/",
            "name": "speed-boost"
        }
    ],
    "next": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/?limit=20&offset=20"
}
```

Comment: There are several ways this code could be failing. The most likely one I see is `this.props.pokemons.data.count` - you're looking up `data` without ever checking if it's defined. Your component is probably mounting and rendering initially, long before your ajax request has finished. `if(!this.props.pokemons.data){ return <div>loading</div>; }`. Another problem is the plural of pokemon is pokemon :P

Comment: Edit: 
Yeah, That has been my assessemnt that component load initial state before request has finished, I tried it but it didnt work. returned an error that render valid react element must be returned. Is there a way to use this fix using one of react life cycle function...maybe componentWillMount? Ha, maybe this way it really doesnt work. Pokemon it is :)

Comment: It also appears that his success message stores the response in the state with the key "data", yet in his mapStateToProps, he accesses it as state.pokemons.   Perhaps that's another reason he's not seeing his data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're rendering your component before the data has loaded. There are many strategies for dealing with this. In no particular order, here are some examples:

## 1. Short circuit the render

You can short circuit the render by returning a loading message if the data isn't there:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        pokemons:state.pokemons
    }
}
class PokemonAbility extends React.Component {
    render(){
        if (!this.props.pokemons.data) {
            return (
                <div>Loading...</div>
            );
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="header">
                    <h1>Fetch Poke Api with axios</h1>
                </div>
                <main>
                    <h3> Display pokemons abilities </h3>
                    <p>{this.props.pokemons.data.count}</p>
                </main>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PokemonAbility);
```

## 2. Lift the data check to a parent component

You can move the `mapStateToProps` into a higher component, or abstract out the view component, and only render the view when the data is ready:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        pokemons:state.pokemons
    }
}
class SomeHigherComponent extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            this.props.pokemons.data ?
                <PokemonAbility pokemons={this.props.pokemons} /> :
                <div>Loading...</div>
        );
    }
}
```

## 3. Higher order component data checking

You could wrap your components in a "higher order component" (a function that takes a component class and returns a component class) to check if that prop exists before rendering:

```
function EnsurePokemon(ChildComponent) {
    return class PokemonEnsureWrapper extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                this.props.pokemons.data ?
                    <ChildComponent {...this.props} /> :
                    <div>Loading...</div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(EnsurePokemon(PokemonAbility))
```

And you can wrap any child component in this `EnsurePokemon` HOC to make sure it doesn't render until the data has loaded.

Comment: At first, it didn't work. Still produces same issue but when I set state to null in the reducer, it finally worked. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, if the initial state is `{}`, then `this.props.pokemons` will always be true (empty object) - I edited the answer to use `this.props.pokemons.data` instead